# House build in late 1960s- Western gypsum drywall-asbestos

Tags: drywall, asbestos, canada

Wondering if Western Gypsum dryall products contained asbestos. Am planning to take for testing, just looking for a quick answer or link to a list of Canadian products that contained asbestos.

Comment: Good chance...until early 1990’s.

Comment: Some or all Canadian drywall contained asbestos until the early 1990s?! Did any drywall sold in the US around 1970 contain asbestos?

Comment: @JimStewart The “asbestos act” was passed in 1989, but they allowed the “use” of existing asbestos gypsum board in warehouses. Crazy, huh?  Canada I don’t know about.

Comment: Did you get the Western gypsum drywall tested for asbestos? I found that name brand in my walls and was wondering if it had asbestos.